# Version Error Integrating PowerBroker Identity Services and Samba on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, samba, active-directory

I am trying to use PBIS (formally likewise open) to enable me to limit permissions on shares to certain AD groups. When I run the command `samba-interop-install --install` I get the following error

```
Found smbd version 4.1.6-Ubuntu
Unsupported smbd version 4.1.6-Ubuntu
Error: ERROR_PRODUCT_VERSION
```

I am running:

- The latest version of PBIS from http://download1.beyondtrust.com/Technical-Support/Downloads/PowerBroker-Identity-Services-Open-Edition/?Pass=True
- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
- Samba version `Version 4.1.6-Ubuntu`

From what I can find on the internet this is a common issue with version 4.x of samba. I am wondering if anyone has had luck setting up this type of environment and if so what steps they needed to take.

**Update:** I have successful validated the installation of PBIS by logging in an AD user over SSH

Comment: As the asker that's your choice. Let us know if you really want it migrated and we can do that for you. Seems it would be on-topic on either site.

Comment: I am stuck at the same Problem. Installed PBIS 8.2.2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 and my task is to enable users in the domain to mount their home directory from the linux server on their windows clients as a network drive. I suppose setting up samba is the way to go... Please tell me how you fixed it.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: workaround here (involves installing samba 3.x from another repo): http://www.troliver.com/?p=226